# How to convert ics file to pdf format programatically?

Tags: c#

I have an ics file. I want to convert it to pdf format programatically using c#. Can you please tell me how can i do that programatically. Do i need to use any dll for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to approach the ics file as a flat file (as flat text), you can use something like [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) to get to the data through an Object Model. From there on, you'd use e.g. [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to create your pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I successfully got the data from object model and then i used iTextSharp as you mentioned to convert to pdf. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please always mark the answers that worked for you as accepted. This will make others more keen to respond to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a pdf conversion library. There are several available, some paid, some free.

Here'a an example of a free one: http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `.ics` file like with simple text file. So you can use any library which allow to create pdf.

I use [itextsharp](http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/using-c-and-itextsharp-to-create-a-pdf/). You can download it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NET library Aspose.iCal to parse the ICS file

http://www.aspose.com/community/blogs/salman.sarfraz/archive/2008/11/21/where-is-aspose-icalendar.aspx (used to be http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx)

And the using iTextSharp at http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ or similar software create the PDF.